# Fiddler: meaning of striken out requests

Tags: fiddler

I've loaded a saved session from yesterday and some requests are stricken out, what's the meaning of this?

[image]

Comment: Please explain why you're downvoting this, I had a look at the docs can't find an answer there on the first glance, tried googling as well. Don't remeber explicitly changing the style on these. If that's the only way to get this this would be an answer.

Comment: Do you have some filters set? 

Try this:  Go to Help > Troubleshoot.. See if there is a check next to it. 
Rows that would otherwise be hidden are displayed with strikethrough if Troubleshoot is enabled.

For more details look at: http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/faq.asp. The keyword is strikethrough

Comment: I don't have Troubleshoot checked. The this is probably me accidenally pressing the shortcut for strike out I suppose.

Comment: Aah, that would be the "-" sign after selecting the request. The column next to content-type does seem to be missing data only for these requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can right-click the Session and choose Properties to determine the reason for the `ui-strikeout` within the Session's flags.